# Hibernate jpamodelgen does not generate entities from another library

Tags: java, hibernate, jpamodelgen

I am working on a spring boot project. I have entities like bellow:

```
 class Entity extends AbstractEntity{
    }
```

Entity.java is in my project. AbstractEntity.class comes from another library.
I was using eclipselink to generate metamodel. I had no problem because eclipselink does not even generate the AbstractEntity so it generates only:

```
class Entity_ {
}
```

I migrate my projet from eclipselink to hibernate. Hibernate generates well my Entity class but not the AbstractEntity class (which is not in my project).
It generates somthing like this:

```
class Entity_ extends AbstractEntity_ {
}
```

Since AbstractEntity was not generated so I had **cannot found symbol AbstractEntity_** error.

Actually I don't need AbstractEntity to be generated. So is there a way to ignore it or at least to generate it so i avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `AbstractEntity` is annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` or `@Entity`? In that case you are out of luck. The only possible "workaround" is to create this `AbstractEntity_` by hand.

Comment: The Hibernate Metamodel Generator is documented [HERE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#generator). I cannot find anywhere it says that it can't generate stubs for this use case. Perhaps the problem is that it requires the source code to be available?. In this case, the solution is to have the library dependency (if you have control over it) generate the stubs for such super classes and publish them with the artifact.

Comment: This is not how documentation works. The lack of mentioning something usually means that this is not supported. The metamodel generator is an annotation processor which works while compiling Java code, so yes, the source is needed.